# How can I get a Tuple from a list in python (3.3)

Tags: python, list, tuples

So I've been given a module with a list of tuples in it. Each tuple has 3 items, a company code, the company name, and the company price:

```
('bwt', 'bigwilsontrans', 23.4)
```

This list has quite a few items in it. What I've been asked to do is write a program that asks the user for input of the company's code (can be more than one) and returns the tuple from the list with that corresponding code in it.

If the code doesn't match any in the list, that code is ignored. Can anyone help? I'm stuck on how to return the tuple. I am quite new to python so sorry if this seems basic

Comment: What do you mean by "can be more than one". Can the user input more than one code? Do you have redundancies?

Comment: Yes the user could import as many codes as they want.] and each code is separated by a comma (and varying numbers of whitespaces) but i have created a variable which has removed the whitespaces and split the codes. so if the input was (AAA, 123,   DDD) it returns:
AAA
123
DDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `list_` be the list of tuples and `c_code` the company code, read from input via `raw_input` or from some GUI via some control (if you need help with that, please tell me.

You could use either list comprehension:

```
matching_results = [t for t in list_ if t[0] == c_code]
```

or the built-in `filter` function:

```
matching_results = filter(lambda t: t[0]==c_code, list_)
```

Be careful with version 2: in Python 3, `filter` is generator-style, i.e. it does not create a list, but you can iterate over it. To get a list in Python 3, you would have to call `list(...)` on this generator.

**EDIT**

If you have a list of company codes, `c_codes`, you can do

```
matching_results = [t for t in list_ if t[0] in c_codes]
```

This should be the easiest possible way.

Comment: I tried option two, using the 'list' function as well and it just returned an empty list? Even when the input included codes that are in the module

Comment: What are your data like? The code snippet `(bwt, bigwilsontrans, 23.4)` is somewhat confusing, as `bwt` and `bigwilsontrans` are just not formatted as strings (no "). Could you give sample data?

Comment: Sorry, the tuples are in the format ('bwt', 'bigwilsontrans', 23.4) My mistake, I forget how important punctuation is

Comment: No problem. But then I do not understand why this doesn't work. Maybe you have some encoding issues? Casing? Leading/trailing whitespaces? For me it works, both in Python 2 and 3

Comment: As part of the program I have already removed whitespaces from the input. We were told that we should start out by changing the input from aaa, bbb, ccc (whitespaces may vary) to a list in the form of ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'] (as the company codes are in capitals), which I have already done. I now need to use those separate codes to get the corresponding tuples from the list

Comment: I added a new sample for more than one company code, please try this one.

Comment: YES. That returns a list of the matching results. That is what i needed. Hopefully should be able to do the rest myself. Thank you so much! Will definately come back if I have any further issues. Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad this helped... As you are new to SO: If you regard an answer as good, you can vote it up - no matter if it was you own question or someone else's question. For your own question, you can mark an answer as solution, as you already did here.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the individual members of a tuple using indexes as if it was an array, see the  relevant [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) for more info.

So this is a pretty simple matter of grabbing your needle (the company code) from the haystack (a list of tuples)

```
# haystack is a list of tuples
def find_needle(needle, haystack):
  for foo in haystack:
    # foo is a tuple, notice we can index into it like an array
    if foo[0] == needle:
      print foo
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you almost definitely want to use a `dict`.

```
companies = { "bwt": (bigwilsontrans, 23.4),
              "abc": (alphabet, 25.9)
            }
```

Then to look it up, you can simply do:

```
code = int(raw_input("Code: "))
print companies[code]
```

Comment: The company code to be searched for is the first item of the tuple, your keys are the price. Additionally, I guess the OP would need help in converting the list of tuples to a dict programatically.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to know how to convert it into a dict without having to retype the whole module

Answer (score -2):

try:

```
>>>tuple([1, 2, 3])
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: (reputation system in action xD)